# vscode code actions does not show full list of actions for flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

code actions in visual studio code shows only 3 actions for flutter which are all extracting widgets. How can I show more actions like wrapping widgets, removing widgets, etc. I have tried all extensions and changed every setting I found but I still couldn't add them.

Comment: https://github.com/Dart-Code/Dart-Code/issues Work with the developers.

Comment: The actions shown depend on the selection/cursor location where you open the menu. Some of the items are only applicable in certain code locations. If you're not seeing them where you think you should, please include a code example/screenshot.